# How to Increase LaunchBar Width?

Tags: software, launchbar

Is there a way of increasing the width of the [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html) bar? Especially when I enter something that results in a web page, this width is insufficient for showing the full title, not even talking about what I entered.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes.

- Move your mouse curser to the left/right edge of the launch bar. Then you can increase the width.
- Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> to change the width in pre-defined increments.

[image]

Comment: When you hover over the edges your mouse cursor changes it's icon. Unfortunately, you cannot get that icon to see on the screenshot.

Comment: @MaxRied No hurry :)

Comment: Acutually for me the cursor doens't change. Do you know a way to restore its default size (beside deleting its preference file...)?

Comment: @MaxRied There is no setting to reset the width. But I guess it's better anyway to use one that fits your use. The default size is just 'arbitrary'. I'm using v5.1.3 on Lion (in case that has to do anything with you not seeing the cursor change).

Comment: The problem is that just after I first changed its width a window manager interfered and tried to maxime it :-p. OK, thanks, I'm using 5.2.907. I'll file a bug report and a feature request.